# Cannot set properties of null in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two elements that are supposed to appear depending on whether the condition is true or false but on one of them I need to use `useRef` hook but it doesn't work. Even though the element sometimes renders first, I still get the error `Cannot set properties of null`. I need to edit the second element's value when it renders with its reference but the code crashes so I can't do anything. Code looks like this:

```
inputRef.current.value="Some text"
{condition ? <SomeOtherComponent /> : <input type="text" ref={inputRef} />}
```

Comment: Because it's render based on condition and `ref` not assigned to element

Comment: `<condition ?` is invalid syntax.

Comment: declare the conditional component and assign the ref before rendering and store it, but why are you assigning text to the ref? Do you want it to store a reference to the element or just a bit of text?

Comment: Please check the `condition` value inside `useEffect`. When it's true then set the value.

Answer (score 2):

You have few options to fix that

1. Remove ref on input and set value directly by
   `value={'Some text'}`.
2. Render input and leave ref as it's but hide input
   by css based on condition.
3. Create useEffect with listener on condition and when
   condition is falsy set the `current.value`.